# jQuery : other links inside div element link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I separate with all the icons still in the div element?

Basically, inside div, I have 4 things to click. The last  was made to link for the whole div element click. The middle  elements were for specific icon clicks. But now, for specific icon clicks, I want the clicks to connect to their own links. For example, if one clicks github png , it should go to github link, but now the google div link overwrites it. For whatever I click, I only connect to one link, which I do not intend.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".Apps").click(function(){
            window.open($(this).find("a").last().attr("href"));
            return false;
        });                             
    });
</script>

    <div class="Apps">
        <p><b>Web Dev Project 3</b><br><i>(coming soon)</i></p>
        <a href="https://github.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="https://github.com/apple-touch-icon-114.png" width="30" height="30"/></a> 
        <a href="http://google.com" target="blank">
        <img id="logo" src="http://cclub.slc.engr.wisc.edu/images/Under-Construction.gif" width="30" height="30"/></a>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="blank"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please make your problem more clear. What link are you talking about?

Comment: Set higher `z-index` on icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the anchors:

```
$(".Apps").click(function(e){
    if (! $(e.target).closest('a').length ) {
        window.open($(this).find("a").last().attr("href"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @RobertKeenan your empty `<a>` tag takes up no space on the screen so it cannot be clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no such concept as an `<a>` being "connected with" a containing element. Instead of that, why not just catch "click" events on the `<div>` and filter out ones that aren't on the icons:

```
$('div.Apps').on("click", ":not(a img)", function() {
  window.location = "http://google.com";
});
```

The way your markup is done, it's hard to tell how there'll be screen area that's not icons inside the container, but presumably you've got padding/margins or something.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would assign different ids for the div and the a link, then inside the a specific link instructions just prevent the default behaviour of the click;

```
$(´#aLinkId´).on(´click´, function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open(whatever here);
});

$(´#aDivId´).on(´click´, function(){
    window.open(other whatever here);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/WPsbb/2/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".Apps").click(function () {
           window.open($(this).find("a").last().attr("href"));
           return false;
       });
       $(".Apps > a").click(function () {
           window.open($(this).attr("href"));
           return false;
       });
   });
```